# is this a valid sentence in pascal?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, pascal

I'm doing a translator from pascal to C and I don't know much of pascal. Would these sentences be a valid sentence in pascal?

```
while primo and (d<i) do 

if (a>5) then
```

Thanks!!

Comment: YES but it's better to grab the freepascal compiler an try it.

Comment: Yes. Also `if a > 5 then` is valid as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's like `while boolean and boolean do ... if ...`; after do there must be only one command, because if you want to loop more lines then you can try `while ... do begin ... end`.